# A query to show pairs based on some condition in a join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Write a query to display distinct pair of patients who are treated by the same doctor.
The following tables are present:

```
doctor:  
d_id  
d_name  

patient:  
p_id  
p_name  

treatment:  
d_id  
p_id  
disease  
medicine
```

The query:

```
Select p1.p_name, p2.p_name
from patient p1, patient p2, treatment t1, treatment t2
where t1.d_id=t2.d_id 
AND t1.p_id<>t2.p_id
AND t1.p_id=p2.p_id
AND t2.p_id=p1.p_id;
```

Can you suggest a better/alternative query (Oracle style) that eliminates duplicate pairs [like (p1,p6) and (p6,p1)]?

Comment: The obvious symmetry-breaking condition is `p1.p_id < p2.p_id` (or vice versa). But I don't know if that was the question.

Comment: Any other methods....? Besides, @Andomar, what are the origins of this condition. Seems more like a tongue-in-cheek solution... a patchwork.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To search for all other patients treated by the same doctor, join the treatments table to itself.  You can use `distinct` to remove duplicates:

```
SELECT   distinct p1.Name
,        p2.Name
FROM     patient p1
JOIN     treatment t1
ON       p1.id = t1.p_id
JOIN     treatment t2
ON       t1.d_id = t2.d_id -- Same doctor
         and t1.p_id < p2.p_id -- Higher patient nr
JOIN     patient p2
ON       p2.id = t2.p_id
```

The condition `t1.p_id < p2.p_id` removes another kind of duplicate, with the patients swapped.  `John, Mary` would be the same pair as `Mary, Join`.  One of thise will be filtered out by the `<` condition.

Answer (score 0):

this will retun list of patients trated by same doctor

Select distinct patient.p_name,treatment.p_id,treatment.d_id from treatment inner join patient on treatment.p_id= patient.p_id group by treatment.d_id